# How to write a number as sum of some other numbers' power

Tags: java, arraylist

Okay firstly I'm sorry I know that I'm not intelligent enough. I'm bad at Math.

I couldn't write an algorithm to this question.

System gives us int x, int y, int boundary and wants us to find which numbers up to boundary satisfy the rule as

```
   some_number = x^i + y^j

   Boundary <= 10^6
   i and j > = 0 
   x and y < 100
```

for example x = 2, y = 3 and boundary= 5,

```
       2 = 2^0 + 3^0
       3 = 2^1 + 3^0
       4 = 2^0 + 3^1
       5 = 2^1 + 3^1
```

output : 2,3,4,5

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
 public static ArrayList<Integer> find_numbers(int x, int y, int boundary) {
        ArrayList<Integer> res = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int num = 0;
        int remain_x = 0, remain_y = 0;
        int count_x = 0, count_y = 0;
        if (boundary >= 2) {
            res.add(2);
        }
        for (int i = 3; i <= boundary; ++i) {
            if(i == x+y)
                res.add(i);
            count_x = 0;
            count_y = 0;
            num = i;
            while (num > 0) {
                remain_x = num % x;
                if (remain_x == 0) {
                    count_x++;
                } else {
                    while (num > 0) {
                        remain_y = num % y;
                        if (remain_y == 0) {
                            count_y++;
                        }
                        num = num / y;
                    }
                }
                num = num / x;
            }
            System.out.println("i =>" +i);
            System.out.println("x=>" + count_x);
            System.out.println("y =>" + count_y);
        }

        return res;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> res = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int x = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 100);
        int y = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 100);
        int boundary = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 1000000);
        res = find_numbers(x, y, boundary );
        System.out.println(res);
    }
}
```

Edit:
I wrote something after reading Shark's comment thank you so much. it's working.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

    public static ArrayList<Integer> find_numbers(int x, int y, int boundary) {
        ArrayList<Integer> res = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int x_k = 0;
        int y_k= 0;
       while(Math.pow(x,x_k)< boundary){
           x_k++;
       }
        while(Math.pow(y,y_k)< boundary){
            y_k++;
        }
        for(int k = 2 ; k<= boundary;++k) {
            for (int i = 0; i < x_k; ++i) {
                for (int j = 0; j < y_k; ++j) {
                    if(k == (int)Math.pow(x,i)+(int)Math.pow(y,j) && !res.contains(k)){
                        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
                        System.out.println(k +" =>" +x + "^" +i +"+"+y+ "^" +j);
                        res.add(k);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return res;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> res = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int x = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 100);
        int y = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 100);
        int boundary = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 1000000);
        res = find_numbers(x,  y,boundary);
        System.out.println("x:" + x);
        System.out.println("y:" + y);
        System.out.println("boundary:" + boundary);
        System.out.println("Result:" + res);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any idea regarding how to approach this task?

Comment: I tried  something like while (num > 0) {
                remain_x = num % x;
                if (remain_x == 0) {
                    count_x++;
                } else {
                    while (num > 0) {
                        remain_y = num % y;
                        if (remain_y == 0) {
                            count_y++;
                        }
                        num = num / y;
                    }
                }
                num = num / x;
            }

Comment: Please put that code in your question. It's hard to read as a comment.

Comment: my problem is I couldn't understand the math part of it so I can't solve. Maybe I should have ask somewhere else I dont know that either. My exam already finished but I wanted to learn how to write that algorithm.

Comment: ok, you're overcomplicating things unnecessarily. How about a different approach - generate two `Set<Integer>` containing values of powers  X^0 to X^k and Y^0 to Y^k respecitvely. (you obrain K as the first power of that number above the boundary). After you have those two sets, you just sum each of those elements and put them a new, third set, as long as they're `<= boundary`. And call the problem done? So for `x=2, y=3, boundary=5` your `k_x` is 2 and `k_y` is 1. if the boundary is 10, `k_x=3` and `k_y=2`. Sum all possible values of `2^0...k_x`  and `3^0...k_y`. Discard the bigger ones.

Comment: @Shark thank you so much. I wrote something it's working correctly :D writing 3 nested for is not good I guess but al least it's working.

Comment: no problem, i figured i'd chime in my idea since all I see here is a bunch of nested `while(true)` loops when the thing i mentioned up there just uses three sequential, bounded for loops.

Comment: Please dont put "the solution" into question. Make sure that your question solely covers your "request", and dont start changing your code in there (besides making it more clear and such).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Main {

    public static ArrayList<Integer> find_numbers(int x, int y, int boundary) {
        ArrayList<Integer> res = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int x_k = 0;
        int y_k= 0;
       while(Math.pow(x,x_k)< boundary){
           x_k++;
       }
        while(Math.pow(y,y_k)< boundary){
            y_k++;
        }
        for(int k = 2 ; k<= boundary;++k) {
            for (int i = 0; i < x_k; ++i) {
                for (int j = 0; j < y_k; ++j) {
                    if(k == (int)Math.pow(x,i)+(int)Math.pow(y,j) && !res.contains(k)){
                        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
                        System.out.println(k +" =>" +x + "^" +i +"+"+y+ "^" +j);
                        res.add(k);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return res;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> res = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int x = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 100);
        int y = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 100);
        int boundary = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 1000000);
        res = find_numbers(x,  y,boundary);
        System.out.println("x:" + x);
        System.out.println("y:" + y);
        System.out.println("boundary:" + boundary);
        System.out.println("Result:" + res);
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay I just started using stackoverflow I'm still learning I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is the most efficient method. Basically, I increment `j` until `x^i + y^j > boundary` then increment `i`.

```
    public static ArrayList<Integer> findNumbers(int x, int y, int boundary) {
        Set<Integer> result = new HashSet<>(); // make sure result is unique
        int powerX = 0, powerY = 0, total = 0, tempX = 0;
        while (true) {
            // calculate x^i
            tempX = (int) Math.pow(x, powerX);
            while (true) {
                // calculate x^i + y^j and compare against boundary
                if ((total = tempX + (int) Math.pow(y, powerY)) <= boundary) {
                    // add result to set and increment y
                    result.add(total);
                    powerY++;
                    // break if y <= 1
                    if (y <= 1)
                        break;
                } else
                    break;
            }
            // break if x <= 1 || x^i > boundary
            if (tempX > boundary || x <= 1)
                break;
            // reset j and increment i
            powerY = 0;
            powerX++;
        }
        // return sorted result
        ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();
        arr.addAll(result);
        arr.sort(null);
        return arr;
    }
```

You might be able refactor the code for better efficiency.